# My program has unexpectedly finished

Tags: c++, windows, qt

this simplest program gives error when compiled in release mode, but compiles fine in debug mode:

```
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc,argv);

    return app.exec();
}
```

ERROR (output from qt's console)

> *Starting C:\excercizes\QT_projects\Line_Counter-build-desktop-Qt_4_7_4_for_Desktop_-_MinGW_4_4__Qt_SDK__Release\release\Line_Counter.exe...
>   The program has unexpectedly finished.
>   C:\excercizes\QT_projects\Line_Counter-build-desktop-Qt_4_7_4_for_Desktop_-_MinGW_4_4__Qt_SDK__Release\release\Line_Counter.exe exited with code -1073741511*

Anyone had this experience?

Comment: Are you sure it can find all the necessary DLLs? You could perhaps use something like DependencyWalker to verify this.

Answer (score 5):

Value -1073741511 is 0xC0000139 hexadecimal, which is error code STATUS_ENTRYPOINT_NOT_FOUND. This means that some DLL is loaded by EXE or another DLL, but it lacks a function that EXE or another DLL is expecting there.

[Event Viewer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_Viewer) may show you what DLL is lacking what function when the error occurs. [Dependency Walker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_Walker) will also show you this, and the whole DLL structure as well.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases this is because the necessary .dll files that the executable is looking for are missing.

The most straightforward approach is to copy the following files from your Qt installation (e.g. `C:\Qt\Qt5.4.2\5.4\mingw491_32\bin`):

- icudt53.dll
- icuin53.dll
- icuuc53.dll
- libstdc++-6.dll
- Qt5Core.dll

... into the /debug and /release directories for the DEBUG and RELEASE configurations.